# Закрыть меню по свайпу вверх

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Как по свайпу вверх закрыть меню ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [jquerymobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/) есть [swipe](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)

И дальше использовать можно вот так вот:

```
$('#menu').on('swipeup',function(){alert("Меню-закройся!");} );
```

Вместо `alert`-а вставьте свое закрытие меню. :)